# Ubuntu 15.10 dual boot hangs when updating grub config

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 15.10

I have an Ubuntu 15.10 installed in a dual boot with Windows 8.1. It worked for a while, and I'm not using Windows 8.1 for a while too. But now I can't install anything on Ubuntu without getting this error

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Even when I use apt-get update this error appears. So I followed the instructions, and used the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but I always get stuck on this:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic 
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
```

And nothing happens... When I use the command `top`, the command `grub-script-+` is consuming the CPU close to 100%.

I searched for problems related to grub, but everything that I found was about problems after updating windows and the Ubuntu option on boot doesn't appears no more. In my case, windows didn't updated, and I can boot on both Ubuntu and Windows normally. I already tried the boot repair, and there I get stuck on the `grup-update: this may take several minutes`. After more than 8 hours with this message, I gave up. Maybe boot repair also get stuck in the `Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration`.

I don't know what is going on, I hope someone can help me.

Many thanks!

Comment: Both Windows and Linux are installed in EFI mode? Is secure boot disabled in BIOS? Is fastboot also switched off in Windows? what exactly are you doing which requires generating/updating grub2 entries?

Comment: It could be that your NVRAM entries are corrupted or full. Try rebooting and checking what's there with `sudo efibootmgr -v`. If there are obvious redundancies, you can try removing them with `sudo efibootmgr -b #### -B`, where `####` is the `Boot####` number of the item you want to remove. Be careful not to remove the entry with which you're currently booting, though! After removing entries, shut down and start up again. (The system might take a bit longer than normal if it does "garbage collection.")